# Troublesome conversion of plain PostgreSQL query to Slick query

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I have a plain PostgreSQL query I'm having trouble translating into slick query. I go stuck in syntax soup when using `groupBy` clause.

```
SELECT u.id AS investor_id,
       u.account_type,
       i.first_name,
       issuer_user.display_name AS issuer_name,
       p.legal_name AS product_name,
       v.investment_date,
       iaa.as_of AS CCO_approval_date,
       v.starting_investment_amount,
       v.maturity_date,
       v.product_interest_rate,
       v.product_term_length,
       i.user_information_id,
       v.id AS investment_id
FROM investors u
JOIN
  ( SELECT ipi.investor_id,
           ipi.first_name,
           ipi.user_information_id
   FROM investor_personal_information ipi
   JOIN
     ( SELECT investor_id,
              MAX(id) AS Max_Id
      FROM investor_personal_information
      GROUP BY investor_id ) M ON ipi.investor_id = m.investor_id
   AND ipi.id = m.Max_Id ) i ON u.id = i.investor_id
JOIN investments v ON u.id = v.investor_id
JOIN sub_products AS sp ON v.sub_product_id = sp.id
JOIN products AS p ON p.id = sp.product_id
JOIN company AS c ON c.id = p.company_id
JOIN issuers AS issuer ON issuer.id = c.issuer_id
JOIN users AS issuer_user ON issuer.owner = issuer_user.id
JOIN investment_admin_approvals AS iaa ON iaa.investment_id = v.id
ORDER BY i.first_name DESC;
```

I've started writing it

```
val query = {
  val investorInfoQuery = (for {
    i <- InvestorPersonalInformation
  } yield (i)).groupBy {
    _.investorId
  }.map {
    case (id, rest) => {
      id -> rest.map(_.id).max
    }
  }
}
```

I know I've to create base queries into one big query and apply joins on them separately. Can anybody help guiding me or providing me some examples? Slick is hard.

Comment: One option is Plain SQL in slick.  You can use your existing sql, and map it to a result type using slick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks pretty simple to write. I am not going to help you write the whole query, I will just give you an example which you can follow to wrtie your query.

Lets say you had following structure and respective table queries defined as `employees`, `emplayeePackages` and `employeeSalaryCredits`

```
case class Employee(id: String, name: String)

case class EmployeePackage(id: String, employeeId: String, baseSalary: Double)

case class EmployeeSalaryCredit(id: String, employeeId: String, salaryCredited: Double, date: ZonedDateTime)
```

Now lets say you want all salary credits for all employees with `employee's id, employee's name, base salary, actual credited salary and date of salary credit` then your query will look like

```
val queryExample = employees
  .join(employeePackages)
  .on({ case (e, ep ) => e.id === ep.employeeId })
  .join(employeeSalaryCredits)
  .on({ case ((e, ep), esc) => e.id === esc.employeeId })
  .map({ case ((e, ep), esc) =>
    (e.id, e.name, ep.baseSalary, esc.salaryCredited, esc.date)
  })
```